# more descriptive IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: f#

Is there a way to get more descriptive Index-Out-Of-Range-Exceptions ?
I thought about just overriding the Item Property like this, but this does not work:

```
type ``[]``<'T> with 
    override arr.Item        
        with get(i) = 
            if i<0 || i >= arr.Length then 
                failwithf "Index %d is Out of Range on Array(%d): %A" i arr.Length arr
            else 
                arr.[i]        
        and set (i: int) (value:'T) = 
            arr.[i] <- value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is just for debugging you can configure VS to break on CLR exceptions (Debug > Exceptions...) to see the invalid index. Otherwise, you could do something like this:

```
let idx = -1
try
    arr.[idx] <- x
with :? System.IndexOutOfRangeException ->
    failwithf "Index out of range: %d" idx
```

Another option is to shadow `Array.get/Array.set`:

```
module Array =
    let get i (arr: 'T[]) =
        if i<0 || i >= arr.Length then 
            failwithf "Index %d is Out of Range on Array(%d): %A" i arr.Length arr
        else 
            arr.[i]
```